# Decrypt TLS traffic on same machine (Mac + mitmproxy/other)

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, wireshark, decryption, tls-intercept

I have a Mac-only application that I need to network-debug, but the application uses TLS. Is there a way I could debug the network traffic of that application with mitmproxy (or any other software) without using another physical machine?

The first thing I thought was to create a transparent proxy with another Mac inside a virtual machine and make that VM use the host machine as a proxy, but the performance is too slow to get the application even start.

Comment: can you configure the proxy settings of the application?

Comment: No, I can't modify any aspect of the application.

Comment: And does changing the system proxy setting have an effect on the application? If this also doesn't work, it will be not easy...

Comment: @Lukas Yes, system settings changes do seem to affect the application.

Comment: I do not know if a Mac even has `iptables` (sorry i'm a linux person), but i'd attempt to route all traffic from the interface that is connected to the LAN into the loopback interface.  Then run mitmp on the loopback interface and add a special rule in iptables for the mitm proxy so it can go out to the LAN.  Again, I'm quite clueless how to do it on a Mac, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the system proxy settings seem to affect the application, you can run any intercepting HTTP proxy (I'd recommend Burp proxy, but you can use mitmproxy, too) on your mac.

Set your system proxy settings to 127.0.0.1 and port 8080 and start the application.

To decrypt TLS, you also need to import the root certificate of the proxy into your trusted certificates.

Comment: I setup the proxy and I do see the HTTP requests in mitmproxy, but the HTTPS ones aren't showing. I added the .p12 cert to the system certs. I also disabled rootless mode. Should I do anything else?

Comment: @alexandernst Well - I can only guess what's wrong... Maybe the application doesn't fully honor the system proxy settings, maybe it doesn't trust mitmproxy's certificates. You could analyze what is going on by viewing the traffic with wireshark and - if you have them - application logs.

Comment: My bad. I added only the HTTP proxy, not the HTTPS (in the system settings). Everything is working flawlessly. Thank you!